# Why is it slower to iterate over a small string than a small list?

Tags: python, performance, cpython, timeit, python-internals

I was playing around with timeit and noticed that doing a simple list comprehension over a small string took longer than doing the same operation on a list of small single character strings. Any explanation? It's almost 1.35 times as much time.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("[x for x in 'abc']")
2.0691067844831528
>>> timeit("[x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']]")
1.5286479570345861
```

What's happening on a lower level that's causing this?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

## TL;DR

- The actual speed difference is closer to 70% (or more) once a lot of the overhead is removed, for Python 2.
- Object creation is **not** at fault. Neither method creates a new object, as one-character strings are cached.
- The difference is unobvious, but is likely created from a greater number of checks on string indexing, with regards to the type and well-formedness. It is also quite likely thanks to the need to check what to return.
- List indexing is remarkably fast.

---

---

```
>>> python3 -m timeit '[x for x in "abc"]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.388 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit '[x for x in ["a", "b", "c"]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.436 usec per loop
```

This disagrees with what you've found...

You must be using Python 2, then.

```
>>> python2 -m timeit '[x for x in "abc"]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.309 usec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit '[x for x in ["a", "b", "c"]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.212 usec per loop
```

Let's explain the difference between the versions. I'll examine the compiled code.

**For Python 3:**

```
import dis

def list_iterate():
    [item for item in ["a", "b", "c"]]

dis.dis(list_iterate)
#>>>   4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f4d06b118a0, file "", line 4>)
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('list_iterate.<locals>.<listcomp>')
#>>>               6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#>>>               9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('a')
#>>>              12 LOAD_CONST               4 ('b')
#>>>              15 LOAD_CONST               5 ('c')
#>>>              18 BUILD_LIST               3
#>>>              21 GET_ITER
#>>>              22 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>              25 POP_TOP
#>>>              26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              29 RETURN_VALUE

def string_iterate():
    [item for item in "abc"]

dis.dis(string_iterate)
#>>>  21           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f4d06b17150, file "", line 21>)
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('string_iterate.<locals>.<listcomp>')
#>>>               6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#>>>               9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('abc')
#>>>              12 GET_ITER
#>>>              13 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>              16 POP_TOP
#>>>              17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              20 RETURN_VALUE
```

You see here that the list variant is likely to be slower due to the building of the list each time.

This is the

```
 9 LOAD_CONST   3 ('a')
12 LOAD_CONST   4 ('b')
15 LOAD_CONST   5 ('c')
18 BUILD_LIST   3
```

part. The string variant only has

```
 9 LOAD_CONST   3 ('abc')
```

You can check that this does seem to make a difference:

```
def string_iterate():
    [item for item in ("a", "b", "c")]

dis.dis(string_iterate)
#>>>  35           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f4d068be660, file "", line 35>)
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('string_iterate.<locals>.<listcomp>')
#>>>               6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#>>>               9 LOAD_CONST               6 (('a', 'b', 'c'))
#>>>              12 GET_ITER
#>>>              13 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>              16 POP_TOP
#>>>              17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              20 RETURN_VALUE
```

This produces just

```
 9 LOAD_CONST               6 (('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

as tuples are immutable. Test:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit '[x for x in ("a", "b", "c")]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.369 usec per loop
```

Great, back up to speed.

**For Python 2:**

```
def list_iterate():
    [item for item in ["a", "b", "c"]]

dis.dis(list_iterate)
#>>>   2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
#>>>               6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
#>>>               9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('c')
#>>>              12 BUILD_LIST               3
#>>>              15 GET_ITER            
#>>>         >>   16 FOR_ITER                12 (to 31)
#>>>              19 STORE_FAST               0 (item)
#>>>              22 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
#>>>              25 LIST_APPEND              2
#>>>              28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
#>>>         >>   31 POP_TOP             
#>>>              32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              35 RETURN_VALUE        

def string_iterate():
    [item for item in "abc"]

dis.dis(string_iterate)
#>>>   2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
#>>>               3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('abc')
#>>>               6 GET_ITER            
#>>>         >>    7 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
#>>>              10 STORE_FAST               0 (item)
#>>>              13 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
#>>>              16 LIST_APPEND              2
#>>>              19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
#>>>         >>   22 POP_TOP             
#>>>              23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The odd thing is that we have the *same* building of the list, but it's still faster for this. Python 2 is acting strangely fast.

Let's remove the comprehensions and re-time. The `_ =` is to prevent it getting optimised out.

```
>>> python3 -m timeit '_ = ["a", "b", "c"]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0707 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit '_ = "abc"'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0171 usec per loop
```

We can see that initialization is not significant enough to account for the difference between the versions (those numbers are small)! We can thus conclude that Python 3 has slower comprehensions. This makes sense as Python 3 changed comprehensions to have safer scoping.

Well, now improve the benchmark (I'm just removing overhead that isn't iteration). This removes the building of the iterable by pre-assigning it:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'iterable = "abc"'           '[x for x in iterable]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.387 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'iterable = ["a", "b", "c"]' '[x for x in iterable]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.368 usec per loop
```

```
>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'iterable = "abc"'           '[x for x in iterable]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.309 usec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'iterable = ["a", "b", "c"]' '[x for x in iterable]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.164 usec per loop
```

We can check if calling `iter` is the overhead:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'iterable = "abc"'           'iter(iterable)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.099 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'iterable = ["a", "b", "c"]' 'iter(iterable)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.1 usec per loop
```

```
>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'iterable = "abc"'           'iter(iterable)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0913 usec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'iterable = ["a", "b", "c"]' 'iter(iterable)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0854 usec per loop
```

No. No it is not. The difference is too small, especially for Python 3.

So let's remove yet more unwanted overhead... by making the whole thing slower! The aim is just to have a longer iteration so the time hides overhead.

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' '[x for x in iterable]'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.12 msec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' '[x for x in iterable]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.77 msec per loop
```

```
>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' '[x for x in iterable]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.32 msec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' '[x for x in iterable]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 msec per loop
```

This hasn't actually changed *much*, but it's helped a little.

So remove the comprehension. It's overhead that's not part of the question:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'for x in iterable: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 msec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'for x in iterable: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 msec per loop
```

```
>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'for x in iterable: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 msec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'for x in iterable: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 935 usec per loop
```

That's more like it! We can get slightly faster still by using `deque` to iterate. It's basically the same, but it's *faster*:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 777 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 usec per loop
```

```
>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 805 usec per loop

>>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 438 usec per loop
```

What impresses me is that Unicode is competitive with bytestrings. We can check this explicitly by trying `bytes` and `unicode` in both:

- `bytes`

  ```
  >>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = b"".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)).encode("ascii") for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'                                                                    :(
  1000 loops, best of 3: 571 usec per loop

  >>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =         [chr(random.randint(0, 127)).encode("ascii") for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 394 usec per loop
  ```

  ```
  >>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = b"".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127))                 for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 757 usec per loop

  >>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =         [chr(random.randint(0, 127))                 for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 438 usec per loop
  ```

  Here you see Python 3 actually *faster* than Python 2.
- `unicode`

  ```
  >>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = u"".join(   chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 800 usec per loop

  >>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =         [   chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 394 usec per loop
  ```

  ```
  >>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = u"".join(unichr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 msec per loop

  >>> python2 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =         [unichr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
  1000 loops, best of 3: 469 usec per loop
  ```

  Again, Python 3 is faster, although this is to be expected (`str` has had a lot of attention in Python 3).

In fact, this `unicode`-`bytes` difference is very small, which is impressive.

So let's analyse this one case, seeing as it's fast and convenient for me:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 777 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; from collections import deque; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'deque(iterable, maxlen=0)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 usec per loop
```

**We can actually rule out Tim Peter's 10-times-upvoted answer!**

```
>>> foo = iterable[123]
>>> iterable[36] is foo
True
```

## These are not new objects!

But this is worth mentioning: indexing *costs*. The difference will likely be in the indexing, so remove the iteration and just index:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable = "".join(chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000))' 'iterable[123]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0397 usec per loop

>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'iterable[123]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0374 usec per loop
```

The difference seems small, but *at least* half of the cost is overhead:

```
>>> python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; iterable =        [chr(random.randint(0, 127)) for _ in range(100000)]' 'iterable; 123'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0173 usec per loop
```

so the speed difference is sufficient to decide to blame it. I think.

So why is indexing a list so much faster?

Well, I'll come back to you on that, but my guess is that's is down to the check for *interned* strings (or cached characters if it's a separate mechanism). This will be less fast than optimal. But I'll go check the source (although I'm not comfortable in C...) :).

---

So here's the source:

```
static PyObject *
unicode_getitem(PyObject *self, Py_ssize_t index)
{
    void *data;
    enum PyUnicode_Kind kind;
    Py_UCS4 ch;
    PyObject *res;

    if (!PyUnicode_Check(self) || PyUnicode_READY(self) == -1) {
        PyErr_BadArgument();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (index < 0 || index >= PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(self)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "string index out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
    kind = PyUnicode_KIND(self);
    data = PyUnicode_DATA(self);
    ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, index);
    if (ch < 256)
        return get_latin1_char(ch);

    res = PyUnicode_New(1, ch);
    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;
    kind = PyUnicode_KIND(res);
    data = PyUnicode_DATA(res);
    PyUnicode_WRITE(kind, data, 0, ch);
    assert(_PyUnicode_CheckConsistency(res, 1));
    return res;
}
```

Walking from the top, we'll have some checks. These are boring. Then some assigns, which should also be boring. The first interesting line is

```
ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, index);
```

but we'd *hope* that is fast, as we're reading from a contiguous C array by indexing it. The result, `ch`, will be less than 256 so we'll return the cached character in `get_latin1_char(ch)`.

So we'll run (dropping the first checks)

```
kind = PyUnicode_KIND(self);
data = PyUnicode_DATA(self);
ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, index);
return get_latin1_char(ch);
```

Where

```
#define PyUnicode_KIND(op) \
    (assert(PyUnicode_Check(op)), \
     assert(PyUnicode_IS_READY(op)),            \
     ((PyASCIIObject *)(op))->state.kind)
```

(which is boring because asserts get ignored in debug [so I can check that they're fast] and `((PyASCIIObject *)(op))->state.kind)` is (I think) an indirection and a C-level cast);

```
#define PyUnicode_DATA(op) \
    (assert(PyUnicode_Check(op)), \
     PyUnicode_IS_COMPACT(op) ? _PyUnicode_COMPACT_DATA(op) :   \
     _PyUnicode_NONCOMPACT_DATA(op))
```

(which is also boring for similar reasons, assuming the macros (`Something_CAPITALIZED`) are all fast),

```
#define PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, index) \
    ((Py_UCS4) \
    ((kind) == PyUnicode_1BYTE_KIND ? \
        ((const Py_UCS1 *)(data))[(index)] : \
        ((kind) == PyUnicode_2BYTE_KIND ? \
            ((const Py_UCS2 *)(data))[(index)] : \
            ((const Py_UCS4 *)(data))[(index)] \
        ) \
    ))
```

(which involves indexes but really isn't slow at all) and

```
static PyObject*
get_latin1_char(unsigned char ch)
{
    PyObject *unicode = unicode_latin1[ch];
    if (!unicode) {
        unicode = PyUnicode_New(1, ch);
        if (!unicode)
            return NULL;
        PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA(unicode)[0] = ch;
        assert(_PyUnicode_CheckConsistency(unicode, 1));
        unicode_latin1[ch] = unicode;
    }
    Py_INCREF(unicode);
    return unicode;
}
```

Which confirms my suspicion that:

- This is cached:

  ```
  PyObject *unicode = unicode_latin1[ch];
  ```
- This should be fast. The `if (!unicode)` is not run, so it's literally equivalent in this case to

  ```
  PyObject *unicode = unicode_latin1[ch];
  Py_INCREF(unicode);
  return unicode;
  ```

Honestly, after testing the `assert`s are fast (by disabling them [I *think* it works on the C-level asserts...]), the only plausibly-slow parts are:

```
PyUnicode_IS_COMPACT(op)
_PyUnicode_COMPACT_DATA(op)
_PyUnicode_NONCOMPACT_DATA(op)
```

Which are:

```
#define PyUnicode_IS_COMPACT(op) \
    (((PyASCIIObject*)(op))->state.compact)
```

(fast, as before),

```
#define _PyUnicode_COMPACT_DATA(op)                     \
    (PyUnicode_IS_ASCII(op) ?                   \
     ((void*)((PyASCIIObject*)(op) + 1)) :              \
     ((void*)((PyCompactUnicodeObject*)(op) + 1)))
```

(fast if the macro `IS_ASCII` is fast), and

```
#define _PyUnicode_NONCOMPACT_DATA(op)                  \
    (assert(((PyUnicodeObject*)(op))->data.any),        \
     ((((PyUnicodeObject *)(op))->data.any)))
```

(also fast as it's an assert plus an indirection plus a cast).

So we're down (the rabbit hole) to:

```
PyUnicode_IS_ASCII
```

which is

```
#define PyUnicode_IS_ASCII(op)                   \
    (assert(PyUnicode_Check(op)),                \
     assert(PyUnicode_IS_READY(op)),             \
     ((PyASCIIObject*)op)->state.ascii)
```

Hmm... that seems fast too...

---

Well, OK, but let's compare it to `PyList_GetItem`. (Yeah, *thanks* Tim Peters for giving me more work to do :P.)

```
PyObject *
PyList_GetItem(PyObject *op, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (i < 0 || i >= Py_SIZE(op)) {
        if (indexerr == NULL) {
            indexerr = PyUnicode_FromString(
                "list index out of range");
            if (indexerr == NULL)
                return NULL;
        }
        PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_IndexError, indexerr);
        return NULL;
    }
    return ((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i];
}
```

We can see that on non-error cases this is just going to run:

```
PyList_Check(op)
Py_SIZE(op)
((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i]
```

Where `PyList_Check` is

```
#define PyList_Check(op) \
     PyType_FastSubclass(Py_TYPE(op), Py_TPFLAGS_LIST_SUBCLASS)
```

<strike>([**TABS! TABS!!!**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/237284d0a73e472f836adc72f090432ae7c5dfad/Include/listobject.h#L49)) ([issue21587](http://bugs.python.org/issue21587))</strike> That got fixed and merged in **5 minutes**. Like... yeah. Damn. They put Skeet to shame.

```
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
```

```
#define PyType_FastSubclass(t,f)  PyType_HasFeature(t,f)
```

```
#ifdef Py_LIMITED_API
#define PyType_HasFeature(t,f)  ((PyType_GetFlags(t) & (f)) != 0)
#else
#define PyType_HasFeature(t,f)  (((t)->tp_flags & (f)) != 0)
#endif
```

So this is normally really trivial (two indirections and a couple of boolean checks) unless `Py_LIMITED_API` is on, in which case... ???

Then there's the indexing and a cast (`((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i]`) and we're done.

So there are definitely *fewer* checks for lists, and the small speed differences certainly imply that it could be relevant.

---

I think in general, there's just more type-checking and indirection `(->)` for Unicode. It seems I'm missing a point, but *what*?

Comment: You are presenting the code as self explanatory; you are even presenting the snippets as conclusions. Unfortunately for me, I can't really follow it. Not saying that your approach to finding out what's wrong isn't solid, but it would be nice if it was easier to follow.

Comment: I tried improving it, but I'm unsure how to make it clearer. Note that I don't write C, so this is a high-level analysis of the code and only the overall concepts are important.

Comment: @Nit I've added. Tell me if it feels lacking. Unfortunately it also highlights that I don't actually know the answer (\*gasp\*).

Comment: I'll give this another day before I accept your answer (I'd love to see something more concrete pop up), but thank you for the very interesting and well researched answer.

Comment: Note that you're shooting at a moving target ;-) This implementation doesn't just differ between Python 2 and Python 3, but also between different releases.  For example, on the current development trunk, the `get_latin1_char()` trick no longer exists in `unicode_getitem()`, but in the lower-level `unicode_char`.  So there's another level of function call now - or not (depending on the compiler and optimization flags used).  At this level of detail, there simply are no reliable answers ;-)

Comment: BTW, show the code for `PyList_GetItem()` too - after error checks it's just `return ((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i]`.  Very short and lean.  String indexing isn't slow, but the code is much more involved than for list indexing.

Comment: @TimPeters Yeah, fine, whatever :P. Done.

Answer (score 33):

When you iterate over most container objects (lists, tuples, dicts, ...), the iterator delivers the objects *in* the container.

But when you iterate over a string, a *new* object has to be created for each character delivered - a string is not "a container" in the same sense a list is a container.  The individual characters in a string don't exist as distinct objects before iteration creates those objects.

Comment: I don't think this is true, actually. You can check with `is`. It *sounds* right, but I really don't think it can be.

Comment: Take a look to @Veedrac answer.

Comment: [`stringobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ba84d1e9a742/Objects/stringobject.c#l1168) shows that `__getitem__` for strings just retrieves the result from a table of stored 1-character strings, so allocation costs for those are only incurred once.

Comment: @user2357112, yes, for plain strings in Python 2 that's a vital point.  In Python 3, all strings are "officially" Unicode and a lot more details are involved (see Veedrac's answer).  For example, in Python 3, after `s = chr(256)`, `s is chr(256)` returns `False` - knowing the type alone isn't enough, because mounds of special cases exist under the covers triggering on the data *values*.

Answer (score 1):

You could be incurring and overhead for creating the iterator for the string.  Whereas the array already contains an iterator upon instantiation.

EDIT:

```
>>> timeit("[x for x in ['a','b','c']]")
0.3818681240081787
>>> timeit("[x for x in 'abc']")
0.3732869625091553
```

This was ran using 2.7, but on my mac book pro i7.  This could be the result of a system configuration difference.

Comment: Even just using the straight iterators, the string is still significantly slower. timeit("[x for x in it]", "it = iter('abc')") = 0.34543599384033535; timeit("[x for x in it]", "it = iter(list('abc'))") = 0.2791691380446508